# Unlink Fails -> open_basedir issue Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, file-upload

Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):

is what i'm getting for the code

```
if (file_exists($thumb)) {
    echo "<b>$thumb</b>";
    $fh = fopen($thumb, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fclose($fh);
    unlink($myFile);
}
```

I can confirm that the path of $thumb is correct.

Any fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `$myFile`? Can you confirm that _it is_ correct?

Comment: Try `realpath($thumb)`. If it's not within the allowed `open_basedir` then reconfigure your php.ini.

Comment: @mario The problem is on the unlink, not the thumb.  realpath() wouldn't make a difference anyway; it just tidies things up, but you end up getting the same file either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your php.ini setup.  The open_basedir configuration setting restricts which areas of the filesystem your PHP script can access; if the file you're trying to delete is outside any directories specified there the unlink() call will fail.