# Phabricator Arcanist has errors ini_set(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, archlinux, phabricator, open-basedir, arcanist

I am running the latest Arch Linux

I have looked at topics like these:

- [Unlink Fails -> open_basedir issue Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295053/unlink-fails-open-basedir-issue-warning-unlink-function-unlink-open-bas)
- [open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Those suggest editing the `php.ini`, adding the directories I need onto `open_basedir`. I have tried commenting out `open_basedir` entirely and **this works** but I am worried about the security implications.

How do I find which file I need to add to `open_basedir`?

Currently I have:

`open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/`

**Edit for people looking at this:** I looked at a co-workers ubuntu ini file, and he has the `open_basedir` expression in there -- so it must be just poorly written (i.e. does not support safe operations)

Comment: "me too", i.e. I have the same problem and the only workaround I found within reasonable time was to disable open_basedir entirely (i.e. comment it out in php.ini)

Comment: This question is not about Arch Linux and it's valid for any other operating system in the world. I can suggest to remove the Tag #archlinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many users over the years tried to install Phabricator on broken popular hosting environments, so a limitation was introduced to reduce the amount of spammy bug reports from these users:

https://we.phorge.it/rP105be01d5f74f4fdff39801bd7551b758c350eef

In short, no. Open Basedir is not supported.

There is a Task about that topic, opened in 2021, and set to very minimum priority:

https://we.phorge.it/T15065

So I can only suggest to disable that limitation for the virtualhost of your Phabricator in the meanwhile. Or, join that Task and share your positive experience with that limitation enabled, and how you fixed the related problems.